# Javascript transition works only after second hover

Tags: javascript, transition

I am new to Javascript. I want to make my image gradually get smaller, and then resize back to its original size. What I have works, but only after hovering over the image 2 times or more.

To be clearer, when I hover my mouse over the image for the first time, it makes a very abrupt transition, but works after that. It did the same thing when using CSS instead.

What I have is this:

```
        function enlargeImage() {
        var logo = document.getElementById('logoname');
        logo.style.opacity = '0.7';
        logo.style.height = 'auto';
        logo.style.width = '800px';
        logo.style.transition = '0.7s';

    }

    function resizeImage() {
        var logo = document.getElementById('logoname');
        logo.style.opacity = '1';
        logo.style.height = 'auto';
        logo.style.width = '900px';
    }
```

Should this work? Or have I coded in a way in which I shouldn't have?

Comment: How are `resizeImage` and `enlargeImage` getting called?

Comment: if you're just going to make it bigger/smaller on hover, why not just leave it to css?

Comment: They're getting called by: <img onmouseover="enlargeImage()" onmouseout="resizeImage()" id="logoname" src="images/ealogo2.png">

Comment: Because it is for class. I need to understand what is and isn't possible, and like I said, I have the same issue when doing it via CSS, anyway.

Comment: Should not the transition list which properties it applies to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I like to leave animations and effects like these to CSS and leave the functionality to Javascript.

```css
#yourImage {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transition: transform .25s ease, opacity .5s ease;
}
        
#yourImage:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" alt="" id="yourImage">
```

When the image is hovered over I transform and resize the image to 0.5% of it's original size and 0.5% of it's original opacity.

I am also using the transition property to set how fast the image transitions when it is resized or when the opacity is changed.

Comment: Based on what you said, I ended up using:

`
#ealogo {
    padding-top: 7%;
    width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    transition: 0.7s;
}

#ealogo:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    transform: scale(0.85);

}


It works a treat! Thank you :)

Comment: @Matt No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The abruption was because of  the height tag inside javascript code. 
 change this

```
height: auto
```

Into `height:400px` or some value instead of auto.

```js
function enlargeImage() {
        var logo = document.getElementById('logoname');
        logo.style.opacity = '0.7';
        logo.style.height = '300px';
        logo.style.width = '400px';
        logo.style.transition = '0.7s';


    }

    function resizeImage() {
        var logo = document.getElementById('logoname');
        logo.style.opacity = '1';
        logo.style.height = '600px';
        logo.style.width = '600px';
        logo.style.transition = '0.7s';

    }
```

```css
img {
  height:300px;
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<img onmouseover="resizeImage()" onmouseout="enlargeImage()"    src='http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg' id="logoname">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, setting a height value did not stop the abruptness.